# SSH Permission denied (publickey). While using Private SSH key

Tags: ssh, private-key

I am trying to use a Private key with ssh, I essentially don't want SSH to ask for a password when I supply a private key on my connection command. On my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file I have the following added:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

With these settings, I am getting asked to supply the password for the root user.

Now when I change PasswordAuthentication to no I am not asked for a password but I get the following error when I supply my private key:
**Permission denied (publickey).**

What should I do?

Comment: Have you added your public key to the user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the target host? Is the permissions on that file correct? Is the permission on your private key correct?

Comment: Yes, I did add the public key on the target servers ```.ssh/authorized_keys```I am getting the same output. I am still beeing asked for a password.

Comment: Did you check those permissions? Is the permission on the `~/.ssh` directory correct?  Have you run the client with the `-vvv` option?  Have you ran the server with the `-vvv` option?